# HTML Form Auto Filler

Tags: javascript, php, web, automation, cross-domain

I have a database of students of my college. I want to use the data to fill admission form on http://www.rmlau.site/urn_r/Registration.aspx

I was trying to use JavaScript but it was not working because of XSS.

Is there a way I can achieve the same?

I am okay with a solution on any platform (Windows/Linux/Web Based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a question for JavaScript but "Is there a way I can achieve the same?" motivated me to answer this. You can use **Selenium** for automated form filling.

Here is a working script to fill the form using selenium in **Python**. Hope this will help you out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.rmlau.site/urn_r/Registration.aspx")

# Students information, loading from excel, csv whatsoever
name = "John Doe"
moName = "Jane"
faName = "Doe Doe"
dob = "17071997"
email = "foo@foo.com"
mobileNo = "090078601"
adharNo = "1231"
course = 'B.Sc. Part One'



time.sleep(3)

# Fill Form
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName").send_keys(name)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMotherName").send_keys(moName)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFatherName").send_keys(faName)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMobilNo").send_keys(mobileNo)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAdhar").send_keys(adharNo)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_course'))
select.select_by_visible_text(course)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDOB").send_keys(dob)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDOB").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDOB").send_keys(dob)


# Submit
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnsave").click()
```

Comment: Selenium seems to be the most accurate solution. But it seems they are using a javascript function **onlyAlphabets** which is preventing selenium IDE to **send_keys** or **type** or even **value** to complete the task. How would you propose to overcome the same?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: well in python, send_keys is working fine and is submitting the form. I'll share a JavaScript based solution if I can submit the form through it.

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't do anything in javascript, however this can be done in php using selenium.

Comment: I had been trying to acheive the same using PHP but was having some troubles. Can we discuss this over email/chat my email is 29.gaurav@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Web Based Solution
first enter a unique column (in this case mobile number) to search from database. Use ajax call for it. then fill all fields using javascript by id method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#search").keyup(function(){
  if($("#search").val().length>=10){ 

  $.ajax({
   type: "post",

   url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>search',

   cache: false,    

   data:'search='+$("#search").val(),

   success: function(response){  

    document.getElementById("name").value = response[0].name;

    document.getElementById("age").value = response[0].age;

    }
   },
   error: function(){      
    alert('Error while request..');
   }
  });
  }
  return false;
   });
 });
```

Comment: @Anandhukrishna VR  using Jquery is definitely a solution but only possible if I have developer access to the above mentioned site. Which I do not have. We are having a internal software running in our college and the mentioned URL is website of the university. Thats why I mentioned cross-domain.

Comment: oh cross-domin tag. i did notice that... next time please mention this type important thinks in title

Comment: Any suggestions now?

Comment: let me check..!